# Error when compiling a document with polyglossia English/Arabic, tabular, longtable and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, polyglossia

Compiling the source without hyperref works perfectly well, but as soon as I use `hyperref` I get compilation errors.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt, DIV=15, BCOR=10mm,parskip=half, headings=normal,openright,headsepline, 
chapterprefix=off]{scrbook}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{chappg}
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linktoc=all,hypertexnames=false,naturalnames=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Mapping=arabicdigits, Scale=1.6]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\bold[Script=Arabic, Mapping=arabicdigits, Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newcommand\ba[1]{\textbf{\bold{#1}}\arabicfont}
\newcommand\rl{\textarabic}
\newcommand{\ty}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\tb}{\textbf}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\small\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{48mm} 
                  |>{\raggedleft  \hspace{0pt}}p{50mm} 
                  |>{\raggedleft   \hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{50mm} |} \hline   
    They (f., pl.) are not students in this school.                                                             &   
    \rl{لَسْنَ طالباتٍ في هذه المدرسةِ.}                                                            &
    \rl{1. هن طالبات في هذه المدرسة.}                                           \\ \cline{1-2}
    They were students in this school.                                                              &
    \rl{كُنَّ طالباتٍ في هذه المدرسةِ.}                                                         &
                                                                                                                                    \\ \cline{1-2}
    They were not students in this school.                                                             &    
    \rl{لم يَكُنَّ طالباتٍ في هذه المدرسةِ.}                                                            &       
                                                                    \\ \hline       
\end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that loading `longtable` after `hyperref` circumvents the issue.

Comment: @egreg odd. I'll see if I can trace but that may just be the way it is, probably you should make an answer anyway saying that, so people find it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Fixed the problem in version 17.5 of bidi and just uploaded to CTAN.

Comment: @user81070 ah thanks I was going to look at the weekend, but sounds like I don't need to now:-)

Comment: @user81070 are  you a regular going under a new name (since you updated bidi?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did not update bidi; I just reported it to the author and he fixed it.

Comment: @user81070 ooh communication, never thought of that:-)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I upgraded MikTex and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that loading `longtable` after `hyperref` circumvents the problem.

This has something to do with the `scrbook` class, though, as if I use `book` instead, the problem doesn't show up.

Comment: Fixed the problem in version 17.5 of bidi and just uploaded to CTAN.